# Compass/orientation model for Android

Tags: javascript, android, api, compass-geolocation

I wonder if you can help regarding a project I'm working on coding in Javascript for an Android application. We're looking for a model to store our compass/orientation values and have found the 2009 w3c document [The Compass API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/system-info/compass.html)

The document suggests the following model be used as a web IDL object:

```
interface Orientation : Object {

    readonly attribute DOMTimeStamp timestamp;
    readonly attribute float        declination;
    readonly attribute float        fieldStrength;
    readonly attribute float        horizontalStrength;
    readonly attribute float        inclination;
    readonly attribute float        x;
    readonly attribute float        y;
    readonly attribute float        z;

};
```

We were wondering if this is the best model to use to create a compass or orientation object, or if there have been any updates or alternatives?

Many thanks

Lesley